# Multiple robots.txt for subdomains in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a site with multiple subdomains and I want the named subdomains robots.txt to be different from the www one.

I tried to use .htaccess, but the FastCGI doesn't look at it.

So, I was trying to set up routes, but it doesn't seem that you can't do a direct rewrite since every routes needs a controller:

```
map.connect '/robots.txt', :controller => ?, :path => '/robots.www.txt', :conditions => { :subdomain => 'www' }
map.connect '/robots.txt', :controller => ?,  :path => '/robots.club.txt'
```

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

(I am using the request_routing plugin for subdomains)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, you probably want to set a mime type in `mime_types.rb` and do it in a `respond_to` block so it doesn't return it as `'text/html'`:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/plain", :txt
```

Then, your routes would look like this:

```
map.robots '/robots.txt', :controller => 'robots', :action => 'robots'
```

For rails3:

```
match '/robots.txt' => 'robots#robots'
```

and the controller something like this (put the file(s) where ever you like):

```
class RobotsController < ApplicationController
  def robots
    subdomain = # get subdomain, escape
    robots = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/config/robots.#{subdomain}.txt")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.txt { render :text => robots, :layout => false }
    end
  end
end
```

at the risk of overengineering it, I might even be tempted to cache the file read operation...

Oh, yeah, you'll almost certainly have to remove/move the existing `'public/robots.txt'` file.

Astute readers will notice that you can easily substitute `RAILS_ENV` for `subdomain`...

Comment: Thanks for posting this, this inspired me - I simplified this technique a little bit and updated for Rails 3. http://www.timbabwe.com/2011/08/rails-robots-txt-customized-by-environment-automatically/

Comment: Thanks I liked your solution.  I've posted a Rails 3.x solution with some slight changes.

Answer (score 11):

Why not to use rails built in views?

In your controller add this method:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def robots
    render :layout => false, :content_type => "text/plain", :formats => :txt
  end
end
```

In the view create a file: `app/views/static_pages/robots.txt.erb` with robots.txt content

In `routes.rb` place:

```
get '/robots.txt' => 'static_pages#robots'
```

Delete the file `/public/robots.txt`

You can add a specific business logic as needed, but this way we don't read any custom files.

Answer (score 2):

As of **Rails 6.0** this has been greatly simplified.

> By default, if you use the :plain option, the text is rendered without
>   using the current layout. If you want Rails to put the text into the
>   current layout, you need to add the layout: true option and use the
>   .text.erb extension for the layout file. [Source](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text)

```
class RobotsController < ApplicationController 
  def robots
    subdomain = request.subdomain # Whatever logic you need
    robots = File.read( "#{Rails.root}/config/robots.#{subdomain}.txt")
    render plain: robots
  end
end
```

In `routes.rb`

```
get '/robots.txt', to: 'robots#robots'
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3:

Create a controller RobotsController:

```
class RobotsController < ApplicationController
#This controller will render the correct 'robots' view depending on your subdomain.
  def robots
    subdomain = request.subdomain # you should also check for emptyness
    render "robots.#{request.subdomain}"
  end
end
```

Create robots views (1 per subdomain):

- views/robots/robots.subdomain1.txt
- views/robots/robots.subdomain2.txt
- etc...

Add a new route in config/routes.rb: (note the :txt format option)

```
match '/robots.txt' => 'robots#robots', :format => :txt
```

And of course, you should declare the :txt format in config/initializers/Mime_types.rb:

```
Mime::Type.register "text/plain", :txt
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't configure your http server to do this before the request is sent to rails, I would just setup a 'robots' controller that renders a template like:

```
def show_robot
  subdomain = # get subdomain, escape
  render :text => open('robots.#{subdomain}.txt').read, :layout => false
end
```

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you could also use a single template instead of a bunch of different files.

Answer (score 0):

I liked TA Tyree's solution but it is very Rails 2.x centric so here is what I came up with for Rail 3.1.x

mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "text/plain", :txt
```

By adding the format in the routes you don't have to worry about using a respond_to block in the controller.
routes.rb

```
match '/robots.txt'   => 'robots#robots',   :format => "text"
```

I added a little something extra on this one.  The SEO people were complaining about duplicated content both in subdomains and in SSL pages so I created a two robot files one for production and one for not production which is also going to be served with any SSL/HTTPS requests in production.

robots_controller.rb

```
class RobotsController < ApplicationController 
  def robots
     site = request.host
     protocol = request.protocol
     (site.eql?("mysite.com") || site.eql?("www.mysite.com")) && protocol.eql?("http://")  ? domain = "production" : domain = "nonproduction"
     robots = File.read( "#{Rails.root}/config/robots-#{domain}.txt")
     render :text => robots, :layout => false
  end
end
```