# Best way to handle dynamic css in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I'm researching a problem for handling dynamic css in a rails app.  Within the app, individual users and/or groups of users can have customized look and feel that is accomplished via CSS.  There will not be any fixed number of "look and feels" or css files, the number will grow as the number of users and groups grows and the look and feel is defined by the users via the  application's admin interface.  Throughout the course of a typical day thousands (it not tens of thousands) of different variations of the css will be served up.  The app will store the pre-built css in mongodb, so there it will not have to pay the price of constructing the css for every request, the question is more about how is the best way to serve up this dynamic css content.  I've seen other questions like [this one][1] that speak to using erb or sass, but some of these answers are dated by several years so I wanted to make sure there wasn't a better answer with Rails 3.

Comment: Instead of storing the css in mongodb, why not store it in an on-disk css file in the public directory with a filename that is tied to the user's id? That way you could serve the css normally (via a link tag in the head) and take advantage of browser caching. Whenever a change is made, you could just clear the cache and add an edit-time-based cachebuster to the link tag src.

Answer (score 40):

You can **treat your CSS files as resources**, store them on the database, and serve them with [**page caching**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Pages.html), so that you only need to hit the db **once** when the CSS is modified. All later requests will be served directly by the web server from the cache, without ever touching your app or db.

```
# stylesheet.rb
class Stylesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :contents
end

# stylesheets_controller.rb
class StylesheetsController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :show # magic happens here

  def show
    @stylesheet = Stylesheet.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # regular ERB template
      format.css { render :text => @stylesheet.contents, :content_type => "text/css" }
    end
  end
  # the rest is your typical RESTful controller, 
  # just remember to expire the cache when the stylesheet changes
end

# routes.rb
resources :stylesheets

# layouts/application.html.erb
…
<link href="<%= stylesheet_path(@current_user.stylesheet) %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I am trying this approach but running into a problem.  I have a background image on the body element in my css but this is not being requested when the css is requested.

Comment: My background image renders correctly if I use `background: url('/assets/image.jpg')`

Comment: I had to embed the stylesheet_path(resource) route and add .css to it for my browser to interpret my link tag as a css type, along with the type='text/css' like so: "#{stylesheet_link_tag(stylesheet)}.css"

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have worked with this a couple of times but they were definitely fixed no of CSS files to choose from. Its should be the same more or less.

One of things I used alot was the **content_for** blocks. Basically

```
<% content_for :css do %>
 // some css file or css content
<% end %>
```

And in the layout

```
<%=  yield :css %>
```

very simple way for managing the layouts.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you a few ideas: [Multiple robots.txt for subdomains in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748882/multiple-robots-txt-for-subdomains-in-rails)

Comment: Without an explanation, this is not quite an 'answer'... but it is a great contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - but needed to serve the modified CSS only once.
I store a couple of constants in a module 'Site' - which I can then use as constants in CSS or as constants throughout the Rails application. I auto-generate the CSS files whenever the Rails application restarts and the CSS input files were modified.

You could do something similar, but reference symbolic names in site_settings.rb
and then fetch those on a per-user basis from MongoDB

http://unixgods.org/~tilo/Ruby/Using_Variables_in_CSS_Files_with_Ruby_on_Rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Now let's say you have some dynamic styling called dynamic.css.scss.erb (the .erb at the end is important!) in app/assets/stylesheets. It will be processed by erb (and then by Sass), and as such can contain stuff like

```
.some_container {
<% favorite_tags do |tag, color| %>
.tag.<%= tag %=> {
    background-color: #<%= color %>;
}
<% end %>
```

}