# Dynamic css - wrong content type

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-headers

I need to add customizable interface for each user in my app. So after some googling i decided to generate css, cache it for every user and link it in views. I found [good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729282/best-way-to-handle-dynamic-css-in-a-rails-app) and used it as example.

So there is pieces of resulting code from my app:

In controller **shedule_themes_controller.rb**:

```
...
def get_css
  respond_to do |format|
    format.css { render :text => "body {\n background-color: blue; \n}", :content_type => Mime::CSS }
  end
end
```

In **layout**:

```
...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<link href="<%= get_css_path %>" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

---

But when i start application, the css doesnt't load. It comes 406 Not Acceptable Error. And response headers are:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

So as you see, response has content/type **text/html** so 406 error is.

Can anyone explain me, why controller response with text/html if request content-type is text/css ?

P.S. I tried to manually send request to localhost:3000/get_css using Google Chrome DEV HTTP CLIENT. I set up Content-Type: text/css and server responded with right css and content-type:

```
body {
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

So probably i made some mistakes in linking dynamic css in my layout?

Thank you!

Comment: try `<link href="<%= get_css_path(:format => :css) %>" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: It works. Thank you! You can post this comment as answer so i could mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the requested url. `<%= get_css_path %>` will return `/get_css` and hence the controller action with handle this request by the `format.html` part. So you can try to append the format with the url as:

```
<link href="<%= get_css_path(:format => :css) %>" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This will request `/get_css.css` and hence the action will handle with format.css part.